# SOLR LineEntityProcessor - fetched x records, but processed/indexed zero records

Tags: dataimporthandler

I am trying fetch all the hyperlinks from an html page and add them as documents to SOLR.

Here is my DIH config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" name="fds" />
    <dataSource type="FieldReaderDataSource" name="frds" />
    <document>
        <entity name="lines" processor="LineEntityProcessor"
             acceptLineRegex="&lt;a\s+(?:[^&gt;]*?\s+)?href=([&quot;'])(.*?)\1"
            url="/Users/naveen/AppsAndData/data/test-data/testdata.html"
            dataSource="fds" transformer="RegexTransformer">
                <field column="line" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

mergedschema xml file contents

```
<schema name="example-data-driven-schema" version="1.6">
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <!-
     ---
    -->

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="line" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</schema>
```

When I run full-import, the status says

```
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 01s)
Requests: 0 , Fetched: 4 4/s, Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0
```

Am I missing something, please help me out here.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

The id field is defined as required=true, additionally it is defined as uniqueKey. That could be the issue. Can you switch it off and try again?